# Avoid typecasting a slice value in loop

Tags: go

I'm reading an API (JSON) response from a server and I'm supposed to get(if the status is 200 ok) the following responses back.

```
// If I sent a wrong data ..
{ 
  error: "some value",
  message: "... description of the error"
}
```

or

```
// if all is good 
{
  events: [{key1: 1}, {key2: "two"} ... ]
}
```

because I'm not sure about the type of response. 
I'm decoding the response as a `map[string]interface{}`.

```
resp := make(map[string]interface{}, 0)
json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&resp)
```

Later in the code flows I reach a stage where I know that response is an all good one. I need to typecast the `interface{}` back to  `[]map[string]interface{}`.

but I think this does not work ..

```
// This does not work I guess. 
// events := resp["events"].([]map[string]interface{})
```

The only sane way I manage to do this is using.

```
interFace := resp["events"].([]interface{})
for mapInterface := range interFace {
  row := MapInterface.(map[string]interface{})
  // now use the row hence forth
}
```

Can this be done in any other way or any Other approach<sup>1</sup> that would avoid the casting in inside the loop.

*1: Maybe creating a Response struct over here can work. But I would really like to hear any other approaches that I can try before forward with a `struct` approach.*

Comment: In your example code, `events` is not an object (that would be unmarshalled into a `map[string]interface{}`), it's an array (that would be unmarshalled into a `[]interface{}`).

Comment: I posted an answer below, just realized you have a note at the bottom about a struct, why would you not want to use a struct?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a struct that has both the error values and non error values in your struct.

```
type Response struct {
    ErrorMessage string `json:"message"`
    Error string `json:"error"`
    Events []map[string]interface{} `json:"events"`
}
```